# Retrieving large XML files for validation using HTTP multipart

Tags: xml, http, xsd, multipart, xml-validation

We're developing a framework for handling large XML files between web-services. Each XML holds a list of entities representing our data, relevant to the specific user query. In the response there will be the **SAME** entity type and each response should be validated using a pre defined XSD.

Because the XML response can be quite sizable we wanted to use a 'paging' mechanism so that, for example, if the response should contains 6000 entities, we create 3 in-memory 'pages' and send only the first 2000 entities with a hash for the next page the user should ask for.

But then someone suggested we use the HTTP multipart specification, so I started reading and I think I understood how to use it but I didn't understand if the server response contain a whole body that I can validate by an XSD or is it like the 'chunked' response where the body just gets cut?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP multipart is a protocol beneath the level of XML validation, which is defined purely in terms of an XML document.  You would validate the XML as a whole document as usual once received.  (Multipart won't break an XML document up by elements as you're imagining anyway.)  This is no different than validating an XML document from the file system as a whole file regardless of how it's physically stored on disk.  Your HTTP library will handle the details of providing you with the transmitted XML document, and you'll call a validating XML parser on the file as usual.

Comment: So will I be able to run validation once the first part of the response arrives from the server? Or is it like 'chunked' where it breaks the XML response? If the client doesn't ask for the next part, what's the difference between the two?